# Where to cache static generated python code

Tags: python, caching, operating-system

Where is the most appropriate location to store generated python code, which is mostly static in the sense that on a given system, it is only every created once unless the environment/python version etc. changes significantly? I'm only concerned with python 3, so `__pycache__` sounds like a good place. Would that be a good idea? Is `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'__pycache__')` the right way to find that folder?

If your answer depends on the platform, a platform-independent way of identifying that location would be great (e.g. thinking of [appdirs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/appdirs)).

**Edit**: To be more specific, I'm wrapping a dynamic library (`.dll`,`.so`,`.dylib` etc.) that is being updated regularly. It's C-header files are well-structured, such that it is feasible to generate a `ctypes` interface for them on the fly. However, parsing a C-header does take a significant amount of time that one rather would not have every time importing the wrapper.

Comment: Is there a reason why the current directory is a bad choice?

Comment: There are many! The use-case is within a library, and cluttering the current directory with cache files sounds very annoying to me. For a library, this is even worse, as it forces any user of the library to accept that clutter (similar to libraries that use `print`: I hate that). Another reason is efficiency: As I said, these files are expected to change very seldom.

Comment: That's not many, that's one. And it's not even the reason why that mechanism exists.

Comment: I'd have counted two... For your second statement, what mechanism (and which of the two reasons) are you referring to?

Comment: Efficiency is a red herring; dealing with 2x files or 3x files has an immeasurable speed difference unless x is so large that dealing with x files alone is in itself a problem. The other reason (vanity) is a *side effect* of [dealing with Linux distros that *insist* on putting all the source files in the same directory for multiple versions of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/).

Comment: Now I'm completely confused what you're trying to say... It's the generation of the files that is a significant burden, so caching does lead to efficiency. That has nothing to do with the mere loading of files. See my update to the question. Sure, `__pycache__` is there due to multiple python versions using the same source, but that does not immediately make that a bad place to store data does it? Are you suggesting that I should instead use the location of the library module itself (is that what you mean by *current directory*)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126459/discussion-between-burnpanck-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams).